# Number of primitive roots mod $p$ that are not primitive roots mod $p^2$

Tags: number-theory, probability-theory, prime-numbers, poisson-distribution, primitive-roots

Consider the primitive roots of a prime $p$ in the range $1...p$ which are not primitive roots mod $p^2$. Let $n(p)$ be this number. While looking for an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841013/p2-misses-2-primitive-roots), it seems that the number of primitive roots mod $p$ that are not primitive roots mod $p^2$ (call it $n(p)$), follows a Poisson distribution with $\lambda = -\log\log 2$, in the sense that the proportion of primes up to $x$ which have $n(p)= k$ seems to be near
$$ \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!} $$

Here is un updated count up to $p=711539$:

```
   observed expected
0   39 717   39 801
1   14 517   14 588
2    2 804    2 673
3      341      327
4       39       30
5        2        2
6        1        0
```

This seems reasonable to me by the following reason: if you pick $g$ a primitive root mod $p^2$, and $t$ is an integer coprime with $p$, then $g^t$ is a primitive root mod $p$, it will be also a primitive root mod $p^2$ if and only if $p \not|\, t$.

So if you consider the integers $g^{pt}$ ($t=1,\dots,p$, $(t,p-1)=1$), reduce them mod $p^2$ and count how many fall in the interval $(1,p)$ then you have the numbers we are looking for. If you think that $g^{pt}$ can fall "randomly" with equal probability in any set of $p$ incongruent integers mod $p^2$ then it is natural to expect this number to follow a Poisson distribution.

The parameter $\lambda$ of the Poisson distribution should be something like the mean value of $\phi(p-1)/p$. It seems that $\lambda = -\log \log 2$ works fine but it could be any number around.

My question is if there is a way to compute the real value of $\lambda$ (if it exists) and what might be it's real value, or a reason why $\lambda = -\log\log 2$ might or not be a reasonable guess. By the way computing the mean value of $\phi(p-1)/p$ seems to be something around $0.374\dots$ while $-\log\log 2 = 0.3665...$ but the approximation using this constant is worse than using $-\log\log 2$.

Comment: This is a very interesting observation. By the way, the mean value of $\phi(p-1)/p$ is known to be $\prod_p \left(1-\frac1{p(p-1)}\right)$. See [Artin's Conjecture on Primitive Roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots).

Comment: See also [this paper](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6965840) by P. J. Stephens.